# Debian 11 Wake on Touch Screen Interaction

Tags: debian, touch-screen

I recently have moved from ubuntu to debian, and in doing so have discovered that if my screen is off, touching the screen will not turn it on as it did in ubuntu. I have looked around to try and find a solution but cannot, is there some setting somewhere that will allow me to wake the computer when i touch the touch screen?